# How to access eager loaded nested relation data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Using Laravel 5.4, with this

**model relationships:**

```
Painter (has many) Paintings
Hall (has many) Paintings
```

and the inverse:

```
Painting (belongs to one) Painter
Painting (belongs to one) Hall
```

**the Hall Controller index() grabs the collection:**

```
$halls = Hall::with(paintings.painter)->get();
```

**The Hall model has an accessor for Painters:**

```
public function getPaintersAttribute() {
  return \App\Painter::select('painters.*')
    ->join('paintings', 'painter_id', 'painters.id')
    ->where('paintings.hall_id', $this->id)
    ->groupBy('painter.id')
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->get();
}
```

In the template:

```
{{ $hall->painters->count() }}

@foreach ($hall->painters as $painter)
    painter: {{ $painter->name }}
@endforeach
```

This works, but

There are two DB queries for the nested eager loading relation:

```
SELECT * FROM 'paintings' WHERE hall_id IN ( <list of hall_id's> )

SELECT * FROM 'painters' WHERE painter_id IN ( <list of painter_id's for that hall> )
```

And there are also 2*n duplicated painter queries, two for each hall, made by the accessor. One is for count() the other for the loop:

```
SELECT ... WHERE paintings.hall_id = <hall_id_1>
SELECT ... WHERE paintings.hall_id = <hall_id_1>

SELECT ... WHERE paintings.hall_id = <hall_id_2>
SELECT ... WHERE paintings.hall_id = <hall_id_2>
```

....

**The question:**

The eager loading already performs the query for the painters data, using the accessor seems redundant.
But I don't know how to access it, something like

```
$hall->paintings->painters->count()
```

A hasManyThrough is not working, as this relationship is not 
*Hall (has) Painting (has) Paintor*

I can pass a variable to the view from the controller with the data, but seems odd to have to do that as the nested relation is already being loaded.

Is there any other way to access the nested data as a collection in the view?